# What's wrong with this Generator function

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator

Javascript, wrote a generator function, however when I use it I get a never ending print out of attempts by the generator.

```
const safeRandomArithmeticInteger = function* () {
    while (true) {
        let num = (Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).toFixed(0);
        console.log(num, Number.isSafeInteger(num), Number.isInteger(num));
        if (Number.isSafeInteger(num) && Number.isInteger(num)) {
            yield num;
        }
    }
}
safeRandomArithmeticInteger().next();
```

When I look at said output, and check the details, I can see that the `if` statement should be getting `true` not `false` from `Numbers.isSafeInteger` and `Numbers.isInteger`

Sample of output below:

```
52730077330004 false false
1097215472202714 false false
1011510981416660 false false
1859295869285676 false false
6859452450121695 false false
7156141621748663 false false
3074391675895674 false false
2505135084042456 false false
6596532539989655 false false
7101905702113607 false false
7399428120828759 false false
4914312922408833 false false
7374206016552703 false false
4424774260234836 false false
4394752072945714 false false
5290411427736593 false false
6029056323347803 false false
1434824110772298 false false
913200889081366 false false
```

So what am I getting wrong here?

Debugging of above list for your convenience:

```
console.log(52730077330004, Number.isSafeInteger(52730077330004), Number.isInteger(52730077330004));
console.log(1097215472202714, Number.isSafeInteger(1097215472202714), Number.isInteger(1097215472202714));
console.log(1011510981416660, Number.isSafeInteger(1011510981416660), Number.isInteger(1011510981416660));
console.log(1859295869285676, Number.isSafeInteger(1859295869285676), Number.isInteger(1859295869285676));
console.log(6859452450121695, Number.isSafeInteger(6859452450121695), Number.isInteger(6859452450121695));
console.log(7156141621748663, Number.isSafeInteger(7156141621748663), Number.isInteger(7156141621748663));
console.log(3074391675895674, Number.isSafeInteger(3074391675895674), Number.isInteger(3074391675895674));
console.log(2505135084042456, Number.isSafeInteger(2505135084042456), Number.isInteger(2505135084042456));
console.log(6596532539989655, Number.isSafeInteger(6596532539989655), Number.isInteger(6596532539989655));
console.log(7101905702113607, Number.isSafeInteger(7101905702113607), Number.isInteger(7101905702113607));
console.log(7399428120828759, Number.isSafeInteger(7399428120828759), Number.isInteger(7399428120828759));
console.log(4914312922408833, Number.isSafeInteger(4914312922408833), Number.isInteger(4914312922408833));
console.log(7374206016552703, Number.isSafeInteger(7374206016552703), Number.isInteger(7374206016552703));
console.log(4424774260234836, Number.isSafeInteger(4424774260234836), Number.isInteger(4424774260234836));
console.log(4394752072945714, Number.isSafeInteger(4394752072945714), Number.isInteger(4394752072945714));
console.log(5290411427736593, Number.isSafeInteger(5290411427736593), Number.isInteger(5290411427736593));
console.log(6029056323347803, Number.isSafeInteger(6029056323347803), Number.isInteger(6029056323347803));
console.log(1434824110772298, Number.isSafeInteger(1434824110772298), Number.isInteger(1434824110772298));
console.log(913200889081366, Number.isSafeInteger(913200889081366), Number.isInteger(913200889081366));
```

Comment: does yield ever execute? do a console log in the if condition

Comment: Nope, Yield is never called.  I put a console.log into the IF statement and it never gets called.

Comment: number.toFixed() will return a string... try Number.isSafeInteger('123'); it returns false
also is it correct to multiply a random number by the max safe integer? surly you'll get a number that's too big to be safe?

Comment: well that's the problem :p @TolMera

Comment: @antman3351 - sir you are a scholar! Thank you, you've fixed it.